# Filling under plot

Tags: filling

Let say I have this

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 20}, Mesh -> {{1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since `Filling` is not supported  with `ParametricPlot3D`, how can I color the surface between the lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
p = ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 20}, 
   Mesh -> {{1}}, PlotPoints -> 30];

Show[ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], c u/10}, {u, 0, 20}, {c, 0, 1},
   Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 30], p]
```

[image: filled]

Answer (score 5):

Interpreting "between the lines" strictly...

#### Another model for filling

The original answer (below) fills between the curve and the part of the curve just below it. It has the advantage that the filling surface does not overlap itself on the helix, which is what happens if you fill to the bottom.  A slight modification lets the bounds of the filling be any two curves.  With this approach, one can fill to the bottom or to the curve, or to whatever.

```
Block[{f, f2},
 f[u_] := {Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10};
 f2[u_] := f[u - 2 Pi];
 Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[f[u], {u, 0, 20}, Mesh -> {{1}}],
  ParametricPlot3D[(1 - t) f[u] + (t) f2[u],
   {u, 2 Pi, 20}, {t, 0, 1},
   Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> {40, 7}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Filling to the bottom (like [@Jens's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens)), in which the surface overlaps itself where the curve lies above itself.

```
Block[{f, f2, u},
 f[u_] := {Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10};
 f2[u_] = ReplacePart[f[u], 3 -> f[0][[3]]]; (*bottom*)
 Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[f[u], {u, 0, 20}, Mesh -> {{1}}],
  ParametricPlot3D[(1 - t) f[u] + (t) f2[u],
   {u, 0, 20}, {t, 0, 1},
   Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> {40, 7}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Filling to the bottom without overlapping filling; the use of `Max[]` in `f2[]` clips the filling to the low point of the plot of `f` (*code updated*):

```
Block[{f, f2, u, p, bottom},
 f[u_] := {Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10};
 p = ParametricPlot3D[f[u], {u, 0, 20}, Mesh -> {{1}}];
 bottom = Min[Cases[p, GraphicsComplex[pts_, __] :> pts[[All, 3]], Infinity]];
 f2[u_] = MapAt[Max[bottom, #] &, f[u - 2 Pi], 3];
 Show[
  p,
  ParametricPlot3D[(1 - t) f[u] + (t) f2[u],
   {u, 0, 20}, {t, 0, 1},
   Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> {50, 5}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
   Exclusions -> None]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Original answer

I assume there is some function `offset[u]` that determines how far back is the corresponding point below `f[u]`: that is, `f[u - offset[u]]` is to be considered "directly below" `f[u]`.  For the example helix, the offset is the period `2 Pi`.

```
Block[{f, offset},
 f[u_] := {Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10};
 offset[u_] := 2 Pi;
 Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[f[u], {u, 0, 20}, Mesh -> {{1}}],
  ParametricPlot3D[(1 - t) f[u] + (t) f[u - offset[u]],
   {u, offset[0], 20}, {t, 0, 1},
   Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> {40, 7},  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]
  ]
 ]
 (*  same as first plot above  *)
```

The distance between the lines does not have to be constant:

```
Block[{f, offset},
 f[u_] := {Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10 + Cos[Sqrt[30] u]/30};
 offset[u_] := 2 Pi;
 Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[f[u], {u, 0, 20}, Mesh -> {{1}}],
  ParametricPlot3D[(1 - t) f[u] + (t) f[u - offset[u]],
   {u, offset[0], 20}, {t, 0, 1},
   Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> {40, 7}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What is considered "directly above" is given by the definition of `offset` (and `f`), and the points do not have to be aligned vertically (on left).

```
Block[{f, offset},
 f[u_] := {(1 + Sin[Sqrt[10] u]/10) Sin[u], (1 + Sin[4.5 u]/10) Cos[
     u], u/10 + Cos[Sqrt[30] u]/30};
 offset[u_] := 2 Pi;
 Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[f[u], {u, 0, 20}, Mesh -> {{1}}],
  ParametricPlot3D[(1 - t) f[u] + (t) f[u - offset[u]],
   {u, offset[0], 20}, {t, 0, 1},
   Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> {50, 7}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]
[image]

*Update:*
The plot on the right shows filling to `z == 0` using the first filling-to-the-bottom method above. One might have reasons for preferring one to the other.

Comment: Here is what it looks like when the FE has done enough graphing for one session and is about to crash: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OudwE.png)